# JSON-String send via JS XMLhttpRequest looses some parts

Tags: javascript, json, http, encoding

I had to send a JSON-String from client to server. The JSON contains arrays like this, with this HTML-Tag-Fragments:
`"text":["testStart<img src='", 0, "' alt='' width='887' height='433' role='presentation' class='img-fluid atto_image_button_text-bottom'>testEnd"]`

In JS I added the JSON-String to the formdata to send a POST-Request to the server. For this I use XMLHttpRequest; nothing special sofar.
But on the server side, these HTML-Tags are missing. So I get this:
`"text":["testStarttestEnd"]`
The last and the first element of the array are combined and the middle is missing aswell.
Everything else of the JSON is fine and complete.

I tried to encode the whole JSON as Base64, send it and decode it on the server side. This seems to work, but I don't know why.

I had to send HTML-Tags inside of JSON-Strings in the past; it always worked. Is there something about encoding and HTTP-Request I have to know?

Thanks for reading and kind regards!

PS:

This is the JS-Function I wrote:

```
function send_import_form(cmid) {
    input = document.getElementById("import_input")
    if (input.files.length == 0) {
        console.log("no files")
    } else {
        reader = new FileReader(); // I get the JSON-String from a file...
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            console.log(e.target.result)// Everything is complete at this point
            console.log(typeof (e.target.result))
            url = "import_export_quiz.php"
            fdata = new FormData()
            // add JSON to Formdata...
            fdata.append("json", e.target.result)
            console.log(fdata); // Everything is complete at this point

            const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            function reqListener() {
                console.log(this.response);
                // The response shows, that something is missing. 
//The server side just echoes the JSON-String. 

            };
            // Send it to the server
            request.addEventListener("load", reqListener)
            request.open("POST", url);
            request.send(fdata);
        }
        reader.readAsText(input.files[0])
    }
}
```

PPS:
So I found out, that it has something todo with anglebrackets. It seems like they are interpreted in a special way. Everything between the brackets disappears. Why is the case?

Comment: Please provide the JSON (not a snippet from it).

Comment: *"In JS I added the JSON-String to the formdata"*: can you add the code with which you did that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should stringify the json that you are sending, there's a bunch of single quotes and stuff that maybe needs to be escaped? And are you json_encoding the echo on the php side?

for sending

`JSON.stringify(e.target.result)`

and on the php side for reading

`json_decode($_POST["json"],true)`

and for response echo

`echo json_encode(....)`

Comment: I tried JSON.stringify() and json_encode() on the php side and it changes nothing. It still seems to loose some part on the way. 
The quotes may be a problem, but it doesn't seem so. When I add single quotes, they appear on the other side as well. So I receive something like:  ```"text":["test'Start'testEnd"]```

Comment: angle brackets?
let res = e.target.result;
res = res.replace(/\</g,"&lt;");
res = res.replace(/\>/g,"&gt;")

Comment: Yeah thanks! It has something to do with these brackets.